# Is there an easy way to update CSV with an API data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, csv

I have a code that can get the Amazon product price if you gave it's "ASIN" (It's Amazon product identification number)... below you can find the code (I don't think there is a need to read the code anyway).

```
<?php

class AmazonAPI {

    var $amazon_aff_id;
    var $amazon_access_key;
    var $amazon_secret_key;

    var $url_params;
    var $itemID;
    var $xml;

    var $operation;
    var $signature;
    var $response_groups = "Small,Images,OfferSummary";

    var $error_message;
    var $error=0;


    public function __construct($affid, $access, $secret)
    {
        $this->amazon_aff_id = $affid;
        $this->amazon_access_key = $access;
        $this->amazon_secret_key = $secret;
    }

    public function build_url()
    {
        $url = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?";

        $this->response_groups = str_replace(",", "%2C", $this->response_groups);

        $url_params = "AWSAccessKeyId=" . $this->amazon_access_key;
        $url_params .= "&AssociateTag=" . $this->amazon_aff_id;

        if(!empty($this->itemID)) {
            $url_params .= "&ItemId=" . $this->itemID;
        }

        $url_params .= "&Operation=" . $this->operation;
        $url_params .= "&ResponseGroup=" . $this->response_groups;
        $url_params .= "&Service=AWSECommerceService";
        $url_params .= "&Timestamp=" . rawurlencode(gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"));
        $url_params .= "&Version=2013-08-01";

        $this->url_params = $url_params;

        $url .= $url_params;
        $url .= "&Signature=" . $this->generate_signature();

        return $url;
    }

    public function generate_signature()
    {
        $this->signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256",
            "GET\nwebservices.amazon.com\n/onca/xml\n" . $this->url_params,
            $this->amazon_secret_key, True));
        $this->signature = str_replace("+", "%2B", $this->signature);
        $this->signature = str_replace("=", "%3D", $this->signature);
        return $this->signature;
    }

    public function item_lookup($id)
    {
        $this->operation = "ItemLookup";
        $this->itemID = $id;

        $url = $this->build_url();

        $ch = curl_init();  

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        $this->xml = simplexml_load_string($output);
        return $this;
    }

    public function check_for_errors()
    {
        if(isset($this->xml->Error)) {
            $this->error_message = $this->xml->Error->Message;
            $this->error = 1;
        }
        if(isset($this->xml->Items->Request->Errors)) {
            $this->error_message = $this->xml->Items->Request->Errors->Error->Message;
            $this->error = 1;
        }
        return $this->error;
    }

    public function get_item_price($product)
    {
        $price = 0;
        if(isset($product->LowestNewPrice)) {
            $price = $product->LowestNewPrice->Amount;
        } elseif(isset($product->LowestUsedPrice)) {
            $price = $product->LowestUsedPrice->Amount;
        } elseif(isset($product->LowestCollectiblePrice)) {
            $price = $product->LowestCollectiblePrice->Amount;
        } elseif(isset($product->LowestRefurbishedPrice)) {
            $price = $product->LowestRefurbishedPrice->Amount;
        }
        return $price;
    }

    public function get_item_data()
    {
        if($this->check_for_errors()) return null;

        $product = $this->xml->Items->Item;
        $item = new STDclass;
        $item->detailedPageURL = $product->DetailPageURL;
        $item->link = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/".$this->itemID."/?tag=" . $this->amazon_aff_id;
        $item->title = $product->ItemAttributes->Title;
        $item->smallImage = $product->SmallImage->URL;
        $item->mediumImage = $product->MediumImage->URL;
        $item->largeImage = $product->LargeImage->URL;

        $item->price = $this->get_item_price($product->OfferSummary);

        return $item;
    }

}

?>
```

Then i echo the price with this code

```
$amazon = new AmazonAPI("associate-id", "access-key", "secret-key");
$item = $amazon->item_lookup("ASIN")->get_item_data();

echo $item->price;
```

Now if i have a csv sheet like this
https://ibb.co/dHS4EK

can i update the prices on column D and E given the asin found on column B and C,

so for example the value of cell D2 will get it using the following code

```
$amazon = new AmazonAPI("associate-id", "access-key", "secret-key");
$item = $amazon->item_lookup(Value on cell D2)->get_item_data();

echo $item->price;
```

then save the csv file after updating it's prices, is there a simple easy way to do that in maybe php especially that i'm very new to coding?

Edit 1: I need the csv file to import it using WooCommerce import tool which only accept csv files

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't this sort of thing better suited to a database rather than a CSV file?

Comment: @NigelRen Actually i need the csv file to import it using woocommerce import tool which only accept csv format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is:

1. Parse the CSV file into an array. You can use PHP functions for that like [str-getcsv](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-getcsv.php)
2. Find the correct line inside the array with either [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) or a simple foreach loop.
3. Update the respective value with the new price
4. Create a CSV file from the array with [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i just was wondering how can i update the price of each cell, i mean my api code above can only lookup a single asin and can't lookup an array of asins so it will be a 1 api request per each price cell

Comment: Well either you have to look if Amazon provides an API endpoint to retrieve the prices for multiple asins, or you have to do your lookup with 1 api request at a time...